# How to manually mount the virtual file systems, to copy MTD partitions

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded, flash-memory

Linux version 2.6.26.5, ARM Linux Kernel on embedded device, NAND-based device. I'm at Busybox rescue shell (ash), with restricted command set.
How to manually mount the virtual file systems, to copy the MTD flash partitions into /tmp?
I need backup the flash partitions use `nanddump`.

```
# cat /proc/mtd 
dev:    size   erasesize  name
mtd0: 00004000 00004000 "NAND BootAgent"
mtd1: 000fc000 00004000 "Linux Kernel"
mtd2: 00d00000 00004000 "Root"
mtd3: 00100000 00004000 "Config"
mtd4: 00100000 00004000 "Debug"
mtd5: 00000000 00004000 "Data"

nanddump -f /tmp/mtd0.bin /dev/mtd0
```

What virtual file systems I should mount for this? Something like this

```
# mount -t proc proc /proc
# mount -t sysfs sysfs /sys
# mount -t tmpfs tmpfs /tmp
# mount -t tmpfs none /dev
# mknod -m 666 /dev/zero c 1 5
# mknod -m 666 /dev/null c 1 3
# mkdir /dev/pts
# mount -t devpts none /dev/pts
```

or I need use commands like this

```
mount -t proc proc /proc
mount -t sysfs sysfs /sys
mount -t tmpfs -o size=20M,mode=0755 tmpfs /dev
mdev -s

cd /dev
nanddump -f /tmp/mtd0.bin /dev/mtd0
```

Answer (score 3):

Typically, there will also be a /dev/mtdblockN device, one for each MTD partition.  These are block devices you can use with nanddump, dd, mount, etc.

You need to create a mount point directory some place (mkdir -p /media/mnt) for example.  Then it depends on what file system your NAND partition is using.  For example, I have two UBIFS NAND partitions and would use commands like:

```
/usr/bin/ubiattach /dev/ubi_ctrl -m <MTD_partition> -O <block_size>
/bin/mount -t ubifs ubi1:rootfs0 /media/mnt
```

If the partition has no file system (like a kernel image) then nanddump would work.

```
nanddump -f /tmp/mtd0.bin /dev/mtdblock0
```

If the partition is a data (NOR) flash then dd will work.

```
dd if=/dev/mtdblock1 of=/tmp/mtd1.bin
```

Comment: So, I need to mount every partition in order to dump it?
I mean like this, for example, for nvram file:
`# mknod -m 644 /dev/mtd9        c 90 9`
`# mknod -m 644 /dev/mtdblock9   b 31  9`
`# mount -t jffs2 /dev/mtdblock9 /mnt`